# Слияние массивов

Tags: java

Программе динамически приходит несколько массивов. Как взять из каждого слово (1е слово первого массива-первое слово второго, и тд. Как это сделать?)

UPD:вот, допустим, несколько массивов

```
String[] mice = String[] { "rat", "bat", "meat" };
String[] cheese = String[] { "moloko", "korova", "sheika" };
```

нужно, чтобы программно получились массивы ,скажем,

```
String[] result1 = String[] { "rat", "moloko" };
String[] result2 = String[] { "bat", "korova" };
String[] result3 = String[] { "meat", "sheika" };
```

strings в массивах может быть сколько угодно, они после парсенья приходят.. Помогите

Comment: Покажите пример кода, с которым у вас проблема.

Comment: @Nofate , обновил вопрос

Comment: создаёш новый массив, равный количеству вх. массивов, делаешь цикл и вставляй в этот массив [0] элемент. Сам хоть пробовал , погромист ?

Comment: @arg, я начинающий

Comment: @arg, зачем мне 1 массив,когда у меня их должно быть по кол-ву слов в массиве

Comment: то что ты делаеш - называется параллельные массивы. за них ломают руки и увольняют с работы.

Comment: @arg, не всегда, им есть одно интересное применение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, вы хотите попарно слить два массива в массив пар.

```
    String[] mice = new String[] {"rat", "bat", "meat" };
    String[] cheese = new String[] {"moloko", "korova", "sheika"};

    String[][] pairs = new String[mice.length][];

    for (int i = 0; i < mice.length; i++) {
        pairs[i] = new String[] { mice[i], cheese[i] };
    }
```

Comment: а случаем, не знаете, как потом эти пары в strings.xml вставить программно?

Comment: что  такое strings.xml, и как оно должно выглядеть?

Comment: чувствую, для андроид вы не разрабатываете..)